# How to count dashboard control on google chart dashboard

Tags: google-visualization

What i want to do is count the values that i have on 2 or more ControlWrapper in one column but so far i only realised that i can only see the values betwean 1 ControlWrapper "and" another ControlWrapper and i wish to use a "or" not a "and".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl2kd.png

here is an image of an example on what i am trieng to do, i wish to see the content betwean 1-3 and 6-8 and what i have in return (at least in this example) is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't supply a function to achieve this by default, but you have pretty good tools.
I've made use of their `data.getFilteredRows([{column:X, minValue:XY, maxValue:YY}])`, by simply creating two sliders (like your picture), adding a listener to whenever any of the two are "changed on", checking the minValue and maxValue of both, passing all four values into a function and then setting the view of another chart to the returned rows.

My listeners looks like this

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function () {
    stateChangeFunction();
});
```

The `stateChangeFunction()` looks like this

```
function stateChangeFunction() {
    var lowFilter1 = control.getState().lowValue;
    var highFilter1 = control.getState().highValue;
    var lowFilter2 = control2.getState().lowValue;
    var highFilter2 = control2.getState().highValue;

    customFilterChart.setView({
        'rows': customFilter(lowFilter1, highFilter1, lowFilter2, highFilter2)
    });
    customFilterChart.draw();
};
```

It simply reads the high and low value of both sliders, and then sets the view of my customFilteredChart to the rows that are returned by this function

```
function customFilter(low1, high1, low2, high2) {
    var rows = []
//Using googles own getFilteredRows
    rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        minValue: low1,
        maxValue: high1
    }]);
//Then doing the same with the other two values.
    rows = rows.concat(data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        minValue: low2,
        maxValue: high2
    }]));
//Removing duplicate rows to avoid displaying them twice.
    var uniqueRows = rows.reduce(function(a,b){if(a.indexOf(b)<0)a.push(b);return a;},[]);

    return uniqueRows
}
```

Also I'd like to credit [Christian Landgren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913800/christian-landgren) for [this wonderful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868720/4873917) reply.

And finally, here is the fiddle I made it in: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/31cfvhas/6/)

Comment: I find it intresting on how it is always possible to manipulate the code when they or the librarys dont support such functions. But thank you, this was exacly what i was looking for and thanks to Christian Landgren  as well.